# Replace not working [JS]

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, var

Just a quick question in javascript.

In the following line

```
let str = "This sentence is great (amazing even) [yeah, whatever, screw grammar]"
let newStr = str.replace(/"\["|"\]"|"\("|"\)"|","/," ");
```

When I `console.log(str)`, it gives me the expected string, but when I `console.log(newStr)`, it looks like the `.replace` didn't do anything... it simply returns `str`.

`newStr` should be `"This sentence is great amazing even yeah whatever screw grammar"`

Can anyone resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you have all those `"` in your regex?

Comment: For some reason, if I don't, the brackets act like brackets and make everything red

Comment: My "make everything red", do you mean syntax highlighting is broken in your IDE?

Comment: `str.replace(/[\[\](),]/g, "")`

Comment: `str.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, "")` since you only care about word characters and spaces. This way you don't have to specify every single symbol in the book.

Comment: @ctwheels rip spaces.

Comment: @JakeWeary fixed, oops

Comment: @ctwheels could I do words and .!? punctuations? Sorry, I'm not good with regex

Comment: @EricLee yes you can :) just add anything you want to keep between the brackets! `[^\w\s.!?]`. It basically says "match anything not present in the set, so anything that's **not** a word character, space, dot, exclamation mark, question mark.

Comment: Thank you! SO MUCH

Comment: @ctwheels what if I want to remove certain word characters/ substrings?

Comment: @EricLee then you should declare whatever you want to keep inside the brackets as such: `[^a-yA-Y0-8]`. That set will only match from `a` to `y`, `A` to `Y`, and `0` to `8`, leaving out `zZ9`

Comment: @ctwheels Ok sorry last question: How would I also remove all occurrences of the substring "hello" and "..."?

Comment: You can do an *OR* in regex as such `[^\w\s.!?]|hello|\.{3}`. *OR* is represented by the `|` token in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern is wrong. Below is the correct one,

```js
let str = "This sentence is great (amazing even) [yeah, whatever, screw grammar]"
let newStr = str.replace(/\(|\)|\[|\]|,/g,"");
console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `!` and `,`.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks. Updated

Comment: Just to mention, you can get rid of escapes entirely if you use a character class instead. `/[][(),]/g` works too. (`[` is not special within the brackets, nor is `]` when it's the first member.)

Comment: @cHao `'[]'.match(/[][are you sure?]/g)`

Comment: @JakeWeary: Odd...i remember `]` not being special at the beginning. (Maybe it was a C++ or Perl thing...) But `[` is indeed not special within the brackets.

Comment: So yeah, can't get rid of escapes entirely, but almost. `/[\][(),]/g`. I ended up doing this entirely because i was trying to work around broken syntax highlighting.